# Find all matches in a concatenated string of same-length words?

Tags: javascript, regex, string, string-matching

I have a long Javascript string with letters like :

```
"aapaalaakaaiartaxealpyaaraa"
```

This string is actually a chained list of 3-letter-words : `"aap","aal","aak","aai", "art", "axe","alp", "yaa" and "raa"`

In reality I have *many* of these strings, with different word lengths, and they can be up to 2000 words long, so I need the *fastest* way to get all the words that start with a certain string. So when searching for all words that start with `"aa"` it should return :

```
"aap","aal","aak" and "aai"
```

Is there a way to do this with a regex ? It's very important that it only matches on each 3-letter word, so matches *in between* words should not be counted, so `"aar"` should not be returned, and also not `"yaa"` or `"raa"`.

Comment: You could just split the string every 3 characters, loop and compare, a regex would do too.

Comment: Do you want the fastest way, or do you want a regex?  Those may be conflicting goals....

Comment: not homework :) just trying to make some kind of scrabble game

Answer (score 2):

The simple way:

```
var results = [];

for (var i = 0; i < str.length; i += 3) {
    if (str.substring(i, i + 2) === "aa") {
        results.push(str.substring(i, i + 3));
    }
}
```

Don’t ask whether it’s the fastest – just check whether it’s fast enough, first. :)

Comment: I can't see how a regex could be faster.  With sets of 3 and 2 sequential match characters assuming there are no matches (best case) you are still going to do n/3 comparisons. And if every sequences is a match (worst case) you are still doing only 2 times the best case. Regexs aren't magic, it's just a pattern applied to a sequence right?

Comment: @JasonSperske: Yep, but regexes have optimizations sometimes. It all depends on the situation. I haven’t benchmarked these yet, but the results can be unexpected…

Answer (score 2):

How about:

```
var str = 'aapaalaakaaiartaxealpyaaraa';
var pattern = /^aa/;

var result = str.match(/.{3}/g).filter(function(word) {
  return pattern.test(word);
});

console.log(result); //=> ["aap","aal","aak","aai"]
```

Comment: @JasonSperske: I don’t see how…

Comment: You are right, I was way off in interpreting how this block if code was working.

Answer (score 1):

```
"aapaalaakaaiartaxealpyaaraa".replace(/\w{3}|\w+/g,function(m){return m.match(/^aa/)?m+',':','}).split(',').filter(Boolean)
```

Comment: @minitech it's there because without it you'd get `["aap", "aal", "aak", "aai", "", "", "", "", "", ""]`

Comment: Just do `.filter(Boolean)` to get rid of those.

Comment: Ah, sorry, I was talking about `.split(/,+/)`. But I suppose that could leave a trailer.